# Hector slicequery 'where' clause

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cassandra, hector, cassandra-cli

Suppose I have a table ClientHeaders with following columns

```
| UUID | Cliend_id | IP | Country | Date |
```

where UUID is primary key.

I want to use this query:

```
select * from ClientHeaders where Client_id = "123";
```

How can I do it using slicequery of hector.

I know if it was like this : `select * from ClientHeaders where UUID= "123";`

Following would have done the task:

```
sliceQuery.setColumnFamily("ClientHeaders");
sliceQuery.setKey("123");
sliceQuery.setRange("", "", false, 5);
QueryResult<ColumnSlice<String, String>> result = sliceQuery.execute();
```

because UUID is primary key so `sliceQuery.setKey("123");` works with primary key, 
Is there any way I can do the where clause functionality from a non primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you have to use IndexedSlicesQuery

```
StringSerializer stringSerializer = StringSerializer.get();
BytesArraySerializer bas = BytesArraySerializer.get();


IndexedSlicesQuery<String, String, byte[]> indexedSlicesQuery = 
            HFactory.createIndexedSlicesQuery("your keyspace", stringSerializer, stringSerializer, bas);

indexedSlicesQuery.setColumnFamily("ClientHeaders");
indexedSlicesQuery.setColumnNames("UUID","Cliend_id","IP","Country","Date");
indexedSlicesQuery.addEqualsExpression("Client_id", stringSerializer.toBytes("123"));

QueryResult<OrderedRows<String, String, byte[]>> result = indexedSlicesQuery.execute();
```

Comment: Hey.. thanks for answering.. But I m getting this error `The method createIndexedSlicesQuery(Keyspace, Serializer<K>, Serializer<N>, Serializer<V>) in the type HFactory is not applicable for the arguments (String, StringSerializer, StringSerializer, BytesArraySerializer)`

Comment: I solved the above error using `Keyspace keyspace =HFactory.createKeyspace("MyKeyspacename", cluster);` But now, `indexedSlicesQuery.execute();` is throwing exception : `me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HInvalidRequestException: InvalidRequestException(why:No indexed columns present in index clause with operator EQ)`

Comment: yes , for that you have to create index on that particular column name
for e.g.
update column family ClientHeaders with comparator = UTF8Type
and column_metadata=
[{column_name: client_id, validation_class:  LongType, index_type: KEYS}];

note: also mention your required column names in update query and/or do related changes as per requirement

Comment: This solved the previous exception but now throws this one: 
`me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HInvalidRequestException: InvalidRequestException(why:[436c69656e745f4944]=[41622e43442e45462e4748] failed value validation (Expected 8 or 0 byte long (11)))`

Comment: you might have done mistake while adding index to that particular column..if you havent any issue than try recreating CF 

create column family "yourcf" with comparator='your comparator' and key_validation_class = 'your value' and default_validation_class = 'your value' and column_metadata = [{column_name: client_id, validation_class: "yourvalidation class",index_name:client_id_idx, index_type:KEYS }];

also add other column names as well...with/without index_type:KEYS
if you also want other column names in 'where clause' do add them with "index_type:KEYS" parameter

Comment: Thanks alot.. its working now.. So may be there was problem in configuring colum family.
Well now I am getting the result in this format: `Rows({fb99f2d2-ba34-4ab0-92a1-c567fc08d242=Row(fb99f2d2-ba34-4ab0-92a1-c567fc08d242,ColumnSlice([HColumn(Client_ID=MyUser), HColumn(Country=India), HColumn(Date=27.05.2013-:31:55), HColumn(IP Address=111.222.33.44)]))})` Is there any way I can extract the string out of it in variables(like String ip= IP_Address) ?

Comment: for (Row<String, String, String> row : result.get().getList()) {
                
    System.out.println("you row key :"+row.getKey());
    System.out.println("your client_id :"+row.getColumnSlice().getColumnByName("client_id").getValue());
    System.out.println("your ip :"+row.getColumnSlice().getColumnByName("ip").getValue());

}